# PHP character encodings that iconv_strlen function supports?

Tags: php, character-encoding

What character encodings does the iconv_strlen function supports.

And what languages does each character encoding represent?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php

iconv is not a part of PHP, rather PHPs iconv functions are a module which allow access to the iconv lib functionality.

**specific support for encodings is dependent on your systems implementation.**

that said, you probably have the GNU implementation (or can get it)

which supports the following

```
European languages
    ASCII, ISO-8859-{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,13,14,15,16}, KOI8-R, KOI8-U, KOI8-RU, CP{1250,1251,1252,1253,1254,1257}, CP{850,866,1131},         Mac{Roman,CentralEurope,Iceland,Croatian,Romania}, Mac{Cyrillic,Ukraine,Greek,Turkish}, Macintosh

Semitic languages   
    ISO-8859-{6,8}, CP{1255,1256}, CP862, Mac{Hebrew,Arabic}
Japanese
    EUC-JP, SHIFT_JIS, CP932, ISO-2022-JP, ISO-2022-JP-2, ISO-2022-JP-1
Chinese
    EUC-CN, HZ, GBK, CP936, GB18030, EUC-TW, BIG5, CP950, BIG5-HKSCS, BIG5-HKSCS:2001, BIG5-HKSCS:1999, ISO-2022-CN, ISO-2022-CN-EXT
Korean
    EUC-KR, CP949, ISO-2022-KR, JOHAB
Armenian
    ARMSCII-8
Georgian
    Georgian-Academy, Georgian-PS
Tajik
    KOI8-T
Kazakh
    PT154, RK1048
Thai
    ISO-8859-11, TIS-620, CP874, MacThai
Laotian
    MuleLao-1, CP1133
Vietnamese
    VISCII, TCVN, CP1258
Platform specifics
    HP-ROMAN8, NEXTSTEP
Full Unicode
    UTF-8
    UCS-2, UCS-2BE, UCS-2LE
    UCS-4, UCS-4BE, UCS-4LE
    UTF-16, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE
    UTF-32, UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE
    UTF-7
    C99, JAVA 

Full Unicode, in terms of uint16_t or uint32_t (with machine dependent endianness and alignment)
    UCS-2-INTERNAL, UCS-4-INTERNAL

Locale dependent, in terms of `char' or `wchar_t' (with machine dependent endianness and alignment, and with OS and locale dependent semantics)
    char, wchar_t
The empty encoding name "" is equivalent to "char": it denotes the locale dependent character encoding.

When configured with the option --enable-extra-encodings, it also provides support for a few extra     encodings:

European languages
    CP{437,737,775,852,853,855,857,858,860,861,863,865,869,1125}
Semitic languages
    CP864
Japanese
    EUC-JISX0213, Shift_JISX0213, ISO-2022-JP-3
Chinese
    BIG5-2003 (experimental)
Turkmen
    TDS565
Platform specifics
    ATARIST, RISCOS-LATIN1
```